# How to 301 redirect for tags and categories in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi Please sorry if my question was simple or very basic. But please some one tell me how to fix this problem
i need to redirect all my website pages and post from old url to new one

example :

```
blog.mysite.com/posttitle.html
```

301 redirect to

```
mysite.com/blog/posttitle.html
```

Already some rule written in htaccess but it only redirects blog posts and pages.
301 redirection is made only for the blog post and pages. But not for all tags, all Categories and all author pages. the following pages are not redirecting ,

```
blog.mysite.com/tag/mytagname 
blog.mysite.com/categories/categoriesname 
blog.mysite.com/author/authorname
```

how to redirect this to new site

```
mysite.com/blog/tag/mytagname 
mysite.com/blog/categories/categoriesname 
mysite.com/blog/author/authorname
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins that can take care of all this for you. No messing with `.htaccess`. All done by modifying WordPress own rewrite rules

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

If you want to do yourself try adding this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your-site.com/blog/$1 [R=301,
```

This would go before the WordPress specific part of .htaccess 'begin WordPress'. That section can be overwritten by WordPress automatically.